# How to turn off the desktop autoswitching and autofocus by an app on Lubuntu 18.04?

Tags: lubuntu, lxde, openbox, focus

I'm running hugin+panomatic and it makes a new window for every pair of the photos. I tried to move the main window to the second desktop, but it switches desktop every time the new window appears. I'm forced to watch the process of control points search and doing something else is very difficult because I lose the focus of any other window I try to work in every 10 seconds.

Comment: open `obconf` and under the **windows** tab uncheck  `focus new windows when they appear`

Comment: It doesn't work with hugin windows. Seems hugin avoid this option somehow. I've tried every option in obconf GUI. I think the only hope could be in the manual editing of a some config text files or something. (I proceed from the assumption that obconf GUI options doesn't require restart of anything to work)